# How can I solve A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time?

Tags: mysql, laravel, environment-variables, laravel-5.3

My project use laravel 5.3 and mysql

When I run my project, there exist error like this :

```
3/3
QueryException in Connection.php line 770:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

When I connect to my database, there also exist error like this :

[image]

**Update** :

My configuration like this :

I connect to database mysql by sqlyog like this :

[image]

My setting db in env like this :

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=myshop
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

I check on the service tab on task manager, the mysql running :

[image]

Comment: Misconfigured mysql. How did you setup your mysql?

Comment: @Paul Santos, I had update my question. Previously there was no error when I connect via sqlyog. I do not know why this error occurred

Comment: Have you checked your firewall? It might be blocking your tcp-ip connection.

Comment: @Paul Santos, No. I don't check it. How can I check it?

Comment: Hold on, can you try to change the port number in sqlyog to `3380` and see if you can connect?

Comment: @Paul Santos, It's the same. It does not work

Comment: @Paul Santos, Now it works. I turn off windows firewall. Then I turn on windows firewall

Comment: Glad to hear. Now you know what's causing the issue.

Comment: @Paul Santos, Okay. Thanks for your help